# how to load images into a python list and convert to a dataframe object

Tags: python

I am trying to read a bunch of png images in a directory into a python list. After getting the images in the list I would like to resize and do some reshaping. But it always throws an error. Below is the sample of my code.
Well it doesn't really throw an error but it always prints out an empty dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.manifold import Isomap
from scipy import misc
from os import listdir
import glob

dset = []
for image_path in glob.glob("/Documents/Python/DAT210x-master/Module4       /Datasets/ALOI/32/*.png"):
    img = misc.imread(image_path)
    img = img[::2, ::2]
    X = (img / 255.0).reshape(-1)
dset.append(X)
dset = pd.DataFrame(dset)
print(dset)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, `DataFrame` objects are typically initialized from `dict` objects. What happens if you add:

```
dset = {'Pictures': dset}
dset = pd.DataFrame(dset)
```

Comment: It prints out a dataset with pictures as the columns

Comment: And your pictures aren't accessible from that column?

Comment: If that doesn't fix your problem it would be helpful to have more information. Maybe edit your post to show the traceback so we can see what exactly the error you're getting is.